# C: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Tags: c

This is my first time learning about C programming (and I'm still fairly new to programming in general) so apologies if any of my questions seem basic.  I'm done writing my codes and I've spent hours googling and trying to fix this problem on my own now, but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I would appreciate any help!

The error I'm getting is

```
Opening file: input1.txt
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I tried to debug my program on my own but this code is simply too advanced for me to debug.  As I stated earlier, I am still new to programming and I am really lost as to what I'm doing wrong.

I'm attaching the two codes that I've worked on.  Some parts of the code was provided, and I had to fill in the blanks for some of the functions.  I originally posted the entire code but the comments said it was too long, so I tried to cut out as much as possible.

Thank you guys in advance for your help, I appreciate it so much!

main.c:

```
int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    //bunch of codes I did not write//
    FILE *fileptr;
fileptr = fopen(fileName, "r");

struct HashMap *hashTable;
char *word;
while((word = nextWord(fileptr))){
    if((hashMapContainsKey(hashTable, word)) == 0) hashMapPut(hashTable, word, 1);
    else{
        int *t = hashMapGet(hashTable, word);
        (*t)++;
    }
}
fclose(fileptr);

for(int i = 0; i < hashTable->capacity; i++){
    HashLink *tempLink = hashTable->table[i];
    while(tempLink != NULL){
        printf("%s: %d\n", tempLink->key, tempLink->value);
        tempLink = tempLink->next;
    }
}

    // bunch more codes I did not write
}
```

hashMap.c

```
void hashMapCleanUp(HashMap* map)
{
    assert(map != NULL);
    HashLink *link1;
    HashLink *link2;
    for(int x = 0; x < map->capacity; x++){
        link1 = map->table[x];
        while(link2 != NULL){
            link1 = link2->next;
            hashLinkDelete(link2);
            link2 = link1;
        }
    }
        free(map->table);
        map->capacity = 0;
        map->size = 0;
}


int* hashMapGet(HashMap* map, const char* key)
{
    assert(map != NULL);
    int x;
    if(HASH_FUNCTION == hashFunction1) x = hashFunction1(key) % map->capacity;
    else if(HASH_FUNCTION == hashFunction2) x = hashFunction2(key) % map->capacity;
    if(x < 0) x += map->capacity;
    if(map->table[x] != NULL){
        struct HashLink *link1 = (HashLink *)malloc(sizeof(HashLink));
        link1 = map->table[x];
        while(link1 != NULL){
            if(*(link1->key) == *key) return (&(link1->value));
            link1 = link1->next;
        }
            return NULL;
    }else return NULL;
}

void resizeTable(HashMap* map, int capacity)
{
    assert(map != NULL);
    struct HashLink **oldLink = map->table;
    int oldLinkSize = hashMapCapacity(map);
    HashLink *link1;
    HashLink *link2;
    hashMapInit(map, capacity);
    for(int x = 0; x < oldLinkSize; x++){
        link1 = oldLink[x];
        while(link1 != 0){
            hashMapPut(map, link1->key, link1->value);
            link2 = link1;
            link1 = link1->next;
            free(link2);
        }
    }
    free(oldLink);
}

void hashMapPut(HashMap* map, const char* key, int value)
{
    assert(map != NULL);
    int x;
    if(HASH_FUNCTION == hashFunction1) x = hashFunction1(key) % map->capacity;
    else if(HASH_FUNCTION == hashFunction2) x = hashFunction2(key) % map->capacity;
    if(x < 0) x += map->capacity;
    struct HashLink *link1 = malloc(sizeof(struct HashLink));
    assert(link1 != 0);
    link1->key = key;
    link1->value = value;
    link1->next = NULL;
    if(hashMapContainsKey(map, key)) hashMapRemove(map, key);
    if(map->table[x]) link1->next = map->table[x];
    map->table[x] = link1;
    map->size++;
    if(hashMapTableLoad(map) >= MAX_TABLE_LOAD) resizeTable(map, (2 * hashMapCapacity(map)));
}

void hashMapRemove(HashMap* map, const char* key)
{
    assert(map != NULL);
    int x;
    if(HASH_FUNCTION == hashFunction1) x = hashFunction1(key) % map->capacity;
    else if(HASH_FUNCTION == hashFunction2) x = hashFunction2(key) % map->capacity;
    if(x < 0) x += map->capacity;
    if(*(map->table[x]->key) == *key){
        struct HashLink *link1 = (HashLink *) malloc(sizeof(HashLink));
        link1 = map->table[x];
        link1 = link1->next;
        hashLinkDelete(link1);
        map->size--;
    }else{
        struct HashLink *link1 = (HashLink *)malloc(sizeof(struct HashLink));
        link1 = map->table[x];
        while(link1 != NULL){
            if(*(link1->next->key) == *key){
                struct HashLink *link2 = (HashLink *)malloc(sizeof(struct HashLink));
                link2 = link1->next;
                link1->next = link1->next->next;
                hashLinkDelete(link2);
                map->size--;
                break;
            }
            link1 = link1->next;
        }

    }
}

 int hashMapContainsKey(HashMap* map, const char* key)
{
    assert(map != NULL);
    int x;
    if(HASH_FUNCTION == hashFunction1) x = hashFunction1(key) % map->capacity;
    else if(HASH_FUNCTION == hashFunction2) x = hashFunction2(key) % map->capacity;
    if(x < 0) x += map->capacity;
    struct HashLink *link1 = map->table[x];
    while(link1 != NULL){
        if(strncmp(link1->key, key, 100) == 0) return 1;
        link1 = link1->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

int hashMapSize(HashMap* map)
{
    assert(map != NULL);
    return(map->size);
}

int hashMapCapacity(HashMap* map)
{
    assert(map != NULL);
    return(map->capacity);
}


int hashMapEmptyBuckets(HashMap* map)
{
    assert(map != NULL);
    int emptyBucket = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < map->capacity; x++){
        if(map->table[x] == NULL)
            emptyBucket++;
    }
    return emptyBucket;
}


float hashMapTableLoad(HashMap* map)
{
    assert(map != NULL);
    return (float)map->size / (float)map->capacity;
}
```

I am also attacking the header for hashMap in case it helps (hashMap.h)

```
#ifndef HASH_MAP_H
#define HASH_MAP_H

#define HASH_FUNCTION hashFunction1
#define MAX_TABLE_LOAD .75

typedef struct HashMap HashMap;
typedef struct HashLink HashLink;

struct HashLink
{
    char* key;
    int value;
    HashLink* next;
};

struct HashMap
{
    HashLink** table;
    // Number of links in the table.
    int size;
    // Number of buckets in the table.
    int capacity;
};

HashMap* hashMapNew(int capacity);
void hashMapDelete(HashMap* map);
int* hashMapGet(HashMap* map, const char* key);
void hashMapPut(HashMap* map, const char* key, int value);
void hashMapRemove(HashMap* map, const char* key);
int hashMapContainsKey(HashMap* map, const char* key);

int hashMapSize(HashMap* map);
int hashMapCapacity(HashMap* map);
int hashMapEmptyBuckets(HashMap* map);
float hashMapTableLoad(HashMap* map);
void hashMapPrint(HashMap* map);

#endif
```

Comment: Time to fire up `gdb`....

Comment: You mind creating an [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: And you are really sure you could not, in any way, kind or form, reduce the amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem? *Have you tried?*

Comment: Fyi, `c == EOF` - careful with that. `fgetc` returns `int` for a reason, and `c` should be declared as such accordingly. Also, your hash function should return an *unsigned* integral type. (`unsigned int` or `size_t` are common).

Comment: Sorry guys, I don't post a lot on this side, wasn't sure how much to include.  I revised my post to make it as short as possible.  Thanks for the suggestions :)

Comment: 'I tried to debug my program on my own but this code is simply too advanced for me to debug' yes, all not-hello-world programs are like that, which is why they are broken up into sections that can be individually tested and then debugged.   How do you think that REAL complex software systems get developed?  One line/step/function/process/site at a time.

Comment: In main,, 'struct HashMap *hashTable;'.  Where is that initialized before it is first dereferenced in 'hashMapContainsKey()'??

Comment: 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' that error wil have been generated by some line of code.  When you breakpointed/stepped through with your debugger, which line was it that failed?

Comment: 'I am still new to programming' OK, so why have you wirtten software that is so far beyond your capacity to debug that you have to post it here with 'I am really lost as to what I'm doing wrong'?   Did you write this code, or did you  copy it from somewhere/someone else?

Answer (score 1):

From your `main`:

```
    if(length == 0) free(fileWord);
    fileWord[length] = '\0';
```

This would crash if `length == 0` because you use the array after freeing it.

[EDIT]

Also, in your `hashMapCleanUp` function, change this:

```
void hashMapCleanUp(HashMap* map)
{
   assert(map != NULL);
   HashLink *link1;
   HashLink *link2;
   for(int x = 0; x < map->capacity; x++){
       link1 = map->table[x];
       while(link2 != NULL){
```

into:

```
void hashMapCleanUp(HashMap* map)
{
   assert(map != NULL);
   HashLink *link1;
   HashLink *link2;
   for(int x = 0; x < map->capacity; x++){
       link2 = map->table[x]; //Change this <----------------------
       while(link2 != NULL){
```